# Ruby average value of array of time values (fixnums)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, time

Looking to get the average duration, where duration is in the form of 1.day, 3.months, 2.weeks format..

```
# provided array
a = [1.day, 3.days, 1.week, 4.days]

# desired output
a.average = "3 days"
```

Any way I have tried results in a number of seconds being the output.. for instance:

```
a.inject(:+) = "15 days"
a.inject(:+) / a.size = 324000
```

I've looked at the Linguistics gem, but it only outputs the value as a number (three hundred and twenty four thousand)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def average_days(a)
  seconds = a.inject(:+) / a.size
  minutes = seconds / 60
  days    = (minutes / 1440).round
  "#{days} days"
end
```

Comment: This works well for days, but what if the duration was months, years, decades, centuries, millenia or eons?

Comment: case; when days > 30 then "#{(days/30).round} months"; when days > 365 then "#{(days/365).round} years"; else "#{days} days"

Comment: It depends on what you're ultimately in search of. If you want to display a pretty, human-readable time span and you don't mind that the final result really is a `String` and no longer an `Integer` then you can use `Fixnum.distance_of_time_in_words`. Pass in an int and it gives you a friendly String with the appropriate units. The downside is that it adds approximations like "almost 3 years", which may not want.

Comment: @jdl Fixnum.distance_of_time_in_words ? You mean the distance_of_time_in_words method from ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper ? I suppose that could work, I'd end up having to include that view helper in the model..

Comment: Actually, it's part of Fixnum in Rails 3. If you're using Rails 2.3, then the DateHelper is probably your best bet.

Comment: I ended up with a combo of this answer and @jdl's comment with the DateHelper

Answer (score 1):

```
> a = [1.day, 3.days, 1.week, 4.days]
> (a.inject(0.0) {|sum, n| sum + n} / a.size) / (60 * 60 * 24)
 => 3.75
```

If you insist. Round and/or truncate however you want.

```
((a.inject(0.0) {|sum, n| sum + n} / a.size) / (60 * 60 * 24)).days
```

Comment: 3.75 what? again, desired output is "3 days". If you enter "3.days" into your console, the output is "3 days" - I would like a similar output from the average...

Comment: 3.75 days. Do whatever you want with the value to round, truncate, etc. 15 days / 4 is not "3 days". It's "3.75 days". You didn't specify how you wanted to handle rounding.

Comment: Actually, 15/4 IS 3, 15.0/4.0 is 3.75, its an integer. Your insulting comment is not helpful to the community, nor is your answer, that clearly doesn't fully answer my question.

Comment: @rabbott All you have to do is change the `0.0` to a `0` in the inject if you prefer to keep everything as an integer.