# Average array of times as strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, time, average

I have an array:

```
array = ["0:00:31", "0:00:52", "0:01:05", "0:00:55", "0:01:33", "0:00:05", "0:00:01", 
      "0:05:10", "0:02:40", "0:03:03", "0:01:33", "0:00:00"]
```

and I need to average all of the times in the array that are not equal to `"0:00:00"`. `"0:00:00"` should just be thrown out.

What's the best way to do this? I'm currently looping through the array, removing all of the `0:00:00` values, turning the strings into integers and doing an average - But it seems like a lot of code for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Seems fine to me what you are doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby average value of array of time values (fixnums)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7814154/ruby-average-value-of-array-of-time-values-fixnums)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(sz = array.reject    {|t| t == '0:00:00' }).
            map       {|t| Time.parse t   }.
            reduce(0) {|a, t| a += t.to_i }.to_f / sz.size
```

You want to group these things into functional operations.  Reject the stuff you don't need, then act on the rest.

Here, `reduce` is a viable way to get an array average, [and has been answered before.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9437283/263858)

---

here is an alternative that is slightly more concise, slightly more cryptic

```
(sz = array.reject {|t| t == '0:00:00'     }).
            map    {|t| Time.parse(t).to_i }.
            reduce(:+).to_f / sz.size
```

Comment: Is adding and parsing times like that a rails thing, I cannot get it to work in pure Ruby.

Comment: array.size will return size of an array including zeros. Instead of `reduce(:+)` you can use `.sum`.

Comment: Ruby never ceases to amaze. Thanks for the tip and the introduction to some new methods.

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking NewAlexandria's answer to return average in seconds:

```
(sz = array.reject    {|t| t == '0:00:00' }).
            map       {|t| t.split(":").inject(0){|product,n| product * 60 + n.to_i} }.
            reduce(0) {|a, t| a += t.to_i }.to_f / sz.size
```

Comment: They are the same results, yes, except for your float return val

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting NewAlexandria's answer to work for some reason, here is how I would do it:

```
def average_of_times(array)
    zero_seconds      = ->x{ x=='0:00:00' }
    covert_to_seconds = ->x do
      hours, minutes, seconds = x.split(':').map(&:to_i)
      hours * 3600 + minutes * 60 + seconds
    end

    seconds = array.reject!(&zero_seconds)
             .map(&covert_to_seconds)
             .reduce(:+) / array.size

    Time.at(seconds).utc.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
end
```